# Tableview Cells being populated before viewDidLoad Method

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *categoriesArray;` that gets populated with categories in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method. However I believe `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`is getting executed before the categories can be populated in my `categoriesArray`. Where do I insert my code to populate the `categoriesArray` so that it will be populated when it is called for the table cell method?

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Category Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *category = self.categoriesArray[indexPath.row];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [category valueForKey:@"categoryName"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: how are you populating your data. if its an async request, dont forget to reload the data at the end `[tableView reloadData]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call  `[self.myTableView reloadData];` when  you have your categories array populated. This will reload all the data that is used to construct the table by calling the table view data source and delegate methods (one of them is your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Also, make sure that you are setting the delegate and dataSource properties of tableview correctly.

More information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource